# Is Intellitest Available for .NET Standard Libraries?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, intellitest

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.1 (26403.7).  In some of my projects I have a menu to generate tests with IntelliTest, in other projects this menu option does not exist.

Specifically in .NET Standard Libraries (at a minimum 1.2 and 1.6) the IntelliTest option is not present.

Is IntelliTest not available for .NET Standard Libraries or do I need to install additional plugins or configure additional options?

Comment: The menu is also missing for libraries, targeted multiple frameworks, if they include standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not supported on .NET Standard.
Presently, it is supported only for .NET Framework.

Comment: so what is the alternative way?

Answer (score -1):

Not supported yet, but on roadmap. You can vote up here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-intellitest-support-for-net-corestandard/359250

I didn't find alternative yet.